# Wordpress total number of wordpress posts in query object

Tags: wordpress

How can I find the total number of posts found in the currently looping post loop?

I assume I need to interact with the WP_Query object, I just can't find any decent documentation of how to get it out.

Comment: What do you mean with 'the currently looping post loop'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), there is:

**$found_posts**:
*The total number of posts found matching the current query parameters*

Comment: Any idea if it can be used within this

Comment: if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

Comment: You will have to try for yourself.

Comment: feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer for future reference.